# Dashed lines for a google line chart

Tags: charts, google-visualization

I'd like to have a google line chart with one of the line series a dashed line.

Is this possible using the google jsapi (javascript)?

I'm actually planning on using a ComboChart, with an AreaChart for most of the data, but one series using a LineChart.  And I'd like that line to be a dashed line...

Comment: Have you looked at http://fusioncharts.com/

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Yes, you can.
Just read about the [data table roles](http://code.google.com/intl/fr/apis/chart/interactive/docs/roles.html) on the doc

Every point you draw could be certain (certainty : true) or uncertain (certainty : false). Between two points, if one or both are uncertain, the line between will be dashed.

you just have to do like this :

```
var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
data.addColumn('string', 'Month'); 
data.addColumn('number', 'Sales'); 
data.addColumn({type:'boolean',role:'certainty'}); // certainty col.
data.addRows([
  ['April',1000,  true],
  ['May',  1170,  true],
  ['June',  660,  true],
  ['July', 1030,  false]
]);
var chartLineWithDash = new google.visualization.LineChart(yourDiv);
chartLineWithDash .draw(data);
```

the line between June and July will be dashed.

For the moment it is style "Experimental", but feel free to ask! :)
Hope it has helped you!

Comment: This also works with a dataView.  Set the "data" variable as done above, then you can do var view = new google.visualization.DataView(data).  After that, when  calling view.setColumns() just be sure to include your new column index for the certainty column added.

Answer (score 3):

Please refer : [LineChart Customization](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/lines) Doc by Google

Solution

```
    var options = 
            {
                lineWidth: 2,
                series: {0: {type: 'line',lineDashStyle: [2, 2]}}
            };
    chartLineWithDash.draw(data, options);
```

Example : Run Snippet

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      google.charts.load("current", {packages:["corechart"]});
      google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
      function drawChart() {
        var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable
            ([['X', 'lineDashStyle: [1, 1]', 'lineDashStyle: [2, 2]',
               'lineDashStyle: [4, 4]', 'lineDashStyle: [5, 1, 3]',
               'lineDashStyle: [4, 1]',
               'lineDashStyle: [10, 2]', 'lineDashStyle: [14, 2, 7, 2]',
               'lineDashStyle: [14, 2, 2, 7]',
               'lineDashStyle: [2, 2, 20, 2, 20, 2]'],
              [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10],
              [2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11],
              [3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12],
              [4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13],
              [5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14],
              [6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15],
              [7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16],
              [8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17],
              [9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18]
        ]);

        var options = {
          hAxis: { maxValue: 10 },
          vAxis: { maxValue: 18 },
          chartArea: { width: 380 },
          lineWidth: 4,
          series: {
            0: { lineDashStyle: [1, 1] },
            1: { lineDashStyle: [2, 2] },
            2: { lineDashStyle: [4, 4] },
            3: { lineDashStyle: [5, 1, 3] },
            4: { lineDashStyle: [4, 1] },
            5: { lineDashStyle: [10, 2] },
            6: { lineDashStyle: [14, 2, 7, 2] },
            7: { lineDashStyle: [14, 2, 2, 7] },
            8: { lineDashStyle: [2, 2, 20, 2, 20, 2] }
          },
          colors: ['#e2431e', '#f1ca3a', '#6f9654', '#1c91c0',
                   '#4374e0', '#5c3292', '#572a1a', '#999999', '#1a1a1a'],
        };

        var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
        chart.draw(data, options);
      }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="chart_div" style="width: 900px; height: 500px;"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```